# VBA - Parsing HTML to retrieve a table to excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

I am trying to extract a table from an HTML page.

The HTML looks like:

```
<table class='tableStyle'>
<tr>
<th class='headerValueClass'>Oper Day</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>Interval Ending</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_BUSAVG</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_HOUSTON</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_HUBAVG</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_NORTH</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_SOUTH</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>HB_WEST</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_AEN</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_CPS</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_HOUSTON</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_LCRA</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_NORTH</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_RAYBN</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_SOUTH</th>
<th class='headerValueClass'>LZ_WEST</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>02/10/2017</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>0015</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.76</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>16.71</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>11.72</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>18.32</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.34</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>-2.52</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.07</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>13.79</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>16.62</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>13.76</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>17.48</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>26.37</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.42</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>-1.07</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>02/10/2017</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>0030</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>13.02</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.99</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>10.54</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>15.71</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>13.49</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>-2.03</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>12.86</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>13.19</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.93</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>12.66</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.98</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>22.27</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>14.20</td>
    <td class='labelClassCenter'>-1.29</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get a nice excel table from this.

This is my sub to get the page, but I don't know how to parse the HTML from here.

```
Sub ImportRTPrice()

READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://ercot.com/content/cdr/html/20170210_real_time_spp"
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = ie.Document
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks!
Olivier

Comment: You need to research how to work with the `MSHTML` library API to iterate the DOM elements. I'm sure there's a TON of examples everywhere. As it stands your question isn't about a *specific* programming issue - you're basically asking people to do the work for you, and that's *too broad* for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gets you on your way. Here is what i think you are looking for. Let me know if you have any questions. I also suggest looking into API calls but this will get you on your way this the code you provided above.

```
Sub ImportRTPrice()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim i

Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate "http://ercot.com/content/cdr/html/20170210_real_time_spp"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = ie.Document

On Error Resume Next

For i = 1 To 100 ' may have to adjust
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) =   html.getElementsByClassName("headerValueClass")(i).innerHTML
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) =   html.getElementsByClassName("labelClassCenter")(i).innerHTML
Next i

On Error GoTo 0

ie.quit

Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Have a great day!